# What does a closed question mean?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I guess I thought if a question was closed, it couldn't continue to be answered (at the very least), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So what does closing a question actually accomplish?

Ref: [Do Catholics refer to all martyrs as Saints?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/do-catholics-refer-to-all-martyrs-as-saints)

At the time of this writing it was closed '3 hours ago' and still allowed someone to post an answer '1 hour ago'.

Comment: I'd change the accepted answer to the other one, since it apparently took the answerer 2 hours to formulate :0

Answer (score 6):

Two things to answer here...

First off, closing *does* mean you can't answer it. Except, well... Sometimes, you can. If you've already started writing an answer, you *might* be able to finish writing it and then post. There are checks for this intended to warn you, but sometimes they don't (or can't, as in the case of a disconnected author) work. This is... *mostly* by-design.

The other part, what closing is meant to accomplish, is simple: closing is limbo, not yet deleted but not fully enabled. The intent is to give folks time to debate and improve the question before it is *actually* deleted. So if you see a closed question you think can *and should* be salvaged, try to clean up any outstanding problems with it, and then vote to re-open.